# How to get document id in python search api?

Tags: python, api, search

I'm developing a map site using Google App Engine with Python language, and have used Search API to apply to my site (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/lesson2).  How i get doccument id after put it in an index? I did as below but not get the doc_id:

```
fields = [
    search.TextField(name = 'userid', value = request.userid),
    search.NumberField(name = 'zoom', value = request.zoom),
    search.TextField(name = 'title', value = request.title),
    search.TextField(name = 'content', value = request.content),
    search.GeoField(name = 'location', value = search.GeoPoint(request.lat, request.lng))
]

d = search.Document(fields = fields)
search.Index(name = _INDEX_NAME).put(d)
doc_id = d.doc_id
```

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific. *What* "python search api" are you using?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, i just edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [full documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#Python_Putting_documents_in_an_index):

```
results = search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME).put(d)
doc_id = results[0].id
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel very much.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. This is the first time i ask a question on this site :)